# How to show two stacked xbar graphs with real, not added values for data?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a stacked xbar chart that replicates the following graphic.
[image]

There are actually two stacked charts for each category, one for in-depth, and one for on-site analysis. The graphs also show the totals instead of adding the values together.
Here is my current outcome:

[image]

As you can see, I am only able to get one stacked bar per category, and I had to change the second value in the Human category from 20.3 to 7.3 in order for the bar to end up at the correct position. I'm not sure what I need to add to replicate the graphic. My current MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,
             compat/bar nodes=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{filecontents}{indepth.dat}
  Label               First   Second 
  \text{Environment}   7.9     16.9     
  \text{Human}        13.0     20.3 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{onsite.dat}
  Label               First   Second 
  \text{Environment}   7.9     16.9    
  \text{Human}        13.0     7.3   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,   
    xmin=0,        
    ytick=data,     
    yticklabels from table={onsite.dat}{Label},  
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel pos=left,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={left},
    point meta=rawx
    ]
\addplot table [
 x=First,
 meta=First,
 ]{onsite.dat};
\addplot table [
 x=Second,
 meta=Second,
]{onsite.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```